# Redirect to home page in Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, redirect-url

I want to redirect my site to home page (base URL) in Controller.

```
$this->_redirect();
```

Using above mentioned function gives me the warning to specify the argument.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect()

When I use the following as argument

```
$this->_redirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
```

It just append the base url in my site url which results something like this

- http://example.comhttp://example.com

Which is obviously a 404 page. Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I reckon you should try to the following:

```
$this->_redirect("/");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Brilliant.. you are right, digging more into "Mage_Core_Controller_Varien" and got the result. protected function _redirect($path, $arguments = array())

Comment: @MuhammadSaiid feel free to mark your question as answered so it'll benefits for others ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can try below code

```
$url = Mage::getBaseUrl();
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks for let me know another way to cop this out. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
$this->_redirectUrl('/magento');
```

Where "magento" is my root folder name. (For localhost/magento..)