# get page url when 404 pages called

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, 404-page

I want to log all 404 page in magento 1.9. we want if url contain a word,the page should redirected to specific page

I have rewrite Mage_Cms_IndexController noRoute Method,

But i dont know this correct or not and is it have event in observer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Controller/Router.php controller.

if your front name does not match any route then it will go to line#91

```
if (!$pageId) {
die('404 page');
 return false;
}
```

you can add log there before **return true**

print $identifier into log you will get what user enters actually

```
Mage::log($identifier, null, 'noRoute.log', true);
```

that's it let me know if you faced any issue

Comment: thank you but how can i forward to another page if condition be true?

Comment: yes you can take reference from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/115045/55928) or this [one](https://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-url-redirect-from-controller/) and accept this answer if your problem solved